# Single word for a person who did product managing, coding (developing), designing and testing

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, word-choice, word-usage, vocabulary

I want to combine code + design to Codesign because *code* and *design* have the same **de**.

But I can't combine code + test. Can't combine design + test .

I want to use only one word to express one person who did prodcut managing, coding (develper), designer and tester job.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: ***Consultant**?*

Comment: Jack-of-all-trades

Comment: I don't think there's a single word for that... However, you can say he's a ***multiboxer***. From there on, it's outside my pay bracket.

Comment: You describe a hands-on manager. If you want to invent new words and think your readers will take that seriously, you're on your own. Codesign already has a meaning of joint work.

Comment: design + test = dentist? That's the guy who does "prodcut" [sic].

Comment: Are you looking for a [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) because the first two words have "de" in them? Thus "codesign"? The problem is that looks like "co-design" (to design with another person) or "code-sign" (to apply a security certificate to a piece of code). Combining words to give a new word with both meanings only works if enough of the original [morphemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morpheme) are left intact.

Answer (score 2):

Your role will be more effectively described by straightforward role titles until new buzzwords are created by an ambitious Creative Director, or Project Manager. Applicant Tracking Systems and recruiters may not acknowledge new terminology prior to recognition by the industry.

Simply give yourself 3 role titles separated by a comma, (3 roles more impressive than 1), for example: "User Interface Designer, Front End Developer, Quality Assurance Manager", or "UI Designer, Front End Developer, QA Manager", etc.